# sql search - combine two tables

Tags: sql, search, join

These are my script for search button. Im using SQL for my database
I have two table:

```
upload_data - fields(user_id, file_name, file_size, file_type)
crew - fields(user_id, lname, fname, mname, rank, ship)
```

SCRIPT for search button:

```
$sql="SELECT crew.user_id, crew.lname, crew.fname, crew.mname, crew.rank, crew.ship, upload_data.FILE_NAME
FROM crew INNER JOIN upload_data
ON crew.user_id = upload_data.user_id
WHERE crew.user_id like '%$search%' OR
crew.lname like '%$search%' OR
crew.fname like '%$search%' OR
crew.mname like '%$search%' OR
crew.ship like '%$search%' OR
crew.rank like '%$search%'
ORDER BY crew.lname DESC";
```

My problem now is every time I do the search, it says "1 results found" but it does not show the result.

> Search Results
>
> 1 results found searching for "160"
>
> E-ID  LastName    FirstName   Middle  Rank    Ship    Payslip

Comment: Which RDBMS is this for? Please add a tag to specify whether you're using `mysql`, `postgresql`, `sql-server`, `oracle` or `db2` - or something else entirely.

Comment: Did you overwrite your resource variable in the loop?

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm still new with this. I'm using mysql

Answer (score 0):

Do **echo $sql;** and run the query manually once in your database directly. If you see many rows there, your script might have overwritten your db resource variable. I assume the error message here above is not from your database, but from your own scripts.